# What causes a link to not go through after a user clicks on it?

Tags: macos, firefox, syntax

I'm using Firefox in OS X on a MacBook. Lately, I've tried clicking some links on the Yahoo main page only to be redirected to a blank white page that says "Bad Syntax". Is this the link or the browser or something else entirely?

Comment: Or it says "Requested URL not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many site issues can be caused by corrupt cookies or cache. In order to try to fix these problems, the first step is to clear both cookies and the cache. Note: This will temporarily log you out of all sites you're logged in to. To clear cache and cookies do the following:

1. Go to Firefox > History > Clear recent history or (if no Firefox
   button is shown) go to Tools > Clear recent history
2. Under "Time range to clear", select "Everything".
3. Now, click the arrow next to Details to toggle the Details list active.
4. From the details list, check Cache and Cookies and uncheck everything else. Now click the Clear now button.

Hope this solves your queries